# How to connect AWS Cloud9 environment to VS Code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, react-fullstack

I want to connect my AWS Cloud9 environment to my VS Code i.e. I will write my code in VS Code and it will show changes in my environment.

Is this possible? If it is, please share how to do it - I found it very difficult to work with AWS instance as its IDE is not coder friendly.

Comment: Yes it's possible check out this guide 

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-use-aws-cloud9-to-power-your-visual-studio-code-ide/

Comment: Hi @AliRedha !! I read that but it is not clear to me.